# Translating return receipts and postmaster messages

Tags: email, smtp, email-server, sendmail

I was wondering if it is possible to translate postmaster message (return receipts, notifications, etc), or at least customize them.

I ask this because my users (too) often call me in order to know what is the meaning of messages, and whether their mail has been or not (a very few of them speak english).

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Are these messages generated by your mail system, or by other systems and relayed onto your users?

Comment: As I understand, they are generated by sendmail itself.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR Sendmail's bounce messages are hardcoded into the source code.

If the feature is very important to you you may consider switching to postfix MTA:
http://www.howtoforge.com/configure-custom-postfix-bounce-messages

P.S. I strongly suggest not removing english version of the messages.